# looping through fusiontable results

Tags: javascript

I would like to read some data from a GoogleFusion table and then use the results, being new to javascript, I would like to understand how to expose the results so that I can use it globally, here is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <script src="http://ft2json.appspot.com/api/ft2json.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var results = ft2json.query(
        'SELECT * FROM 1j1kKW9s9CrtZ6_o6MdC-xb0YNWb73rQQYENmzQ', /* Fusion Tables query. */
        function(result) {
            /* Callback function. */
            console.log(result);
        },
        {
            /* Optional parameters. */
            start : 25,
            limit : 50
        }
    );
    console.log('data', results);
    </script>
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

The first `console.log` returns the Object, but the second `console.log('data', results);` returns `Undefined`.

In the Chrome console the `console.log('data', results);` is read first, which I don't understand why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what happened

1. Your query was sent (query function)
2. console.log('data', results) was invoked
3. Your callback function was invoked

The query is asynchronous. So, what happened is that your code keeps running while waiting for the query result. See examples of what you can do below.

Example 1

```
    ft2json.query(
        'SELECT * FROM 1j1kKW9s9CrtZ6_o6MdC-xb0YNWb73rQQYENmzQ', /* Fusion Tables query. */
        function(result) {
            /* Callback function. */
            console.log(result);
            // do stuff with result object here
        },
        {
            /* Optional parameters. */
            start : 25,
            limit : 50
        }
    );
</script>
```

Example 2

```
    var doSomethingWithResult = function (result) {
         // do stuff with result object here
    };

    ft2json.query(
        'SELECT * FROM 1j1kKW9s9CrtZ6_o6MdC-xb0YNWb73rQQYENmzQ', /* Fusion Tables query. */
        function(result) {
            /* Callback function. */
            doSomethingWithResult(result);
        },
        {
            /* Optional parameters. */
            start : 25,
            limit : 50
        }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: so 1. 'query was sent' that is 'var results = '?

why can't I read it from the second console.log, as I want to work with the data?

Comment: @user1598690 It sounds like you are expecting the result to be assigned as the "return value" of the query function. That is not what the query function does. What the query function does is pass the result to the callback function. I am about to edit my answer with examples.

Comment: oh one more thing, in your first example, what i don't understand is how are the /* Optional parameters. */ taken into account, if the '// do stuff with result object here' is before? are these just like a sort of arguments to the ft2json.query?

Comment: @user1598690 I would expect so. I have not used fusion tables before.

Comment: i have one more question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959446/accessing-data-in-javascript-object it is javascript related, i am not sure how to access the Object properties